# Fast combinatoric generator in Python

Tags: python, performance, generator, combinatorics

As part of a large project in python, I need a fast generator function that produces all possible sets of non-negative integer numbers smaller than `n`, such that each set has at most `s` elements and the difference between the largest and smallest numbers in the set is smaller than `w`.

The fastest implementation that I have achieved so far makes use of `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def subsample(n, s, w):
    nn = range(w)
    for p in range(s):
        o = list(itertools.combinations(nn, p+1))
        for t in o:
            yield t
        for _ in range(0, n-w):
            pt = o
            o = [tuple([op + 1 for op in list(u)]) for u in pt]
            for t in list((set(o) ^ set(pt)) & set(o)):
                yield t
```

For instance:

```
In [1]: list(subsample(6,3,3))
Out [1]: [(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4), (4, 5), (3, 5), (0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

But I am convinced that there must be more efficient ways to do this. Is there anything that would make this faster?

Comment: *What is the fastest way?* is a bad way of asking the question. What would be more prone to answers would be along the lines of *Is there anything that would make this faster?*, to which I would answer *not unless you want to screw up the intention of your program*.

Comment: whats your python version ?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? This may be relevant in the case of range; if it's <3, you may consider changing that to xrange in `for p in range(s):` and `for _ in range(0, n-w):`

Comment: @A.J. Apologizes if the question was not good. I have edited it according to your suggestion. @Kasra and @Eithos, I am using python 2.7. The `range` vs `xrange` issue is a good observation, thanks.

Comment: @STU You'll probably get some better answers if you post your question over [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some generators based on algorithms attributed to Knuth.

- `subsets4` generates all subsets of *1..n* having *k* or less elements
- `subsets5` restricts the subsets generated by `subsets4` to those having a max difference of *w*
- `subsets` generates all subsets of *1..n* of length exactly *k*
- `subsets2` restricts the subsets of generated by `subsets` to those having a max difference of *w*

Run the `megatest()` function to test the `subsets5` generator for multiple values of *n*, *k* and *w*.

```
# all subsets of k or less elements of 1..n
def subsets4(n,k):
  a = [ 0 ] * k
  i = 0
  while i >= 0:
    a[i] += 1
    yield a[0:i+1]
    r = a[i]+1
    i += 1
    while i < k and r <= n:
      a[i] = r
      yield a[0:i+1]
      i += 1
      r += 1
    i -= 1
    if a[i] >= n:
      i -= 1

# all subsets of k or less elements of 1..n with max difference <= w
def subsets5(n,k,w):
  a = [ 0 ] * k
  i = 0
  while i >= 0:
    a[i] += 1
    yield a[0:i+1]
    r = a[i]+1
    i += 1
    while i < k and r <= n and r-a[0] <= w:
      a[i] = r
      yield a[0:i+1]
      i += 1
      r += 1
    i -= 1
    if a[i] >= n or a[i]+1-a[0] > w:
      i -= 1

# all subsets of 1..n having exactly k elements
def subsets(n,k):
  a = range(1,k+1)
  while a[0] <= n+1-k:
    yield a
    # find i
    i = k-1
    while i >= 0 and a[i]+k-i >= n+1: i -= 1
    r = a[i]
    a[i] += 1
    j = 2
    i += 1
    while i < k:
      a[i] = r + j
      i += 1
      j += 1

# all subsets of 1..n having exactly k elements and whose max
# difference is w
def subsets2(n,k,w):
  if k > w: return
  a = range(1,k+1)
  while a[0] <= n+1-k:
    yield a
    i = k-1
    while i >= 0 and (a[i]+k-i >= n+1 or a[i]+k-i-a[0] > w) : i -= 1
    r = a[i]
    a[i] += 1
    j = 2
    i += 1
    while i < k:
      a[i] = r + j
      i += 1
      j += 1

def test(n,k,w):
  s1 = [ s for s in subsets4(n,k) if s[-1] - s[0] <= w ]
  s2 = [ s for s in subsets5(n,k,w) ]
  if s1 == s2:
    print "OK", n,k,w
    return 0
  else:
    print "NOT OK", n, k, w
    return 1 

# for s in subsets2(10,3,4): print s
# for s in subsets(10,3): print s
def megatest():
  failed = 0
  for n in xrange(10,20):
    for k in xrange(1,n+1):
      for w in xrange(k,n+1):
        failed += test(n,k,w)
  print "failed:", failed
```

Comment: Hey, this is very good, more than 3 times faster than my implementation: `%timeit [f for f in subsets5(500,6,11)]` gives `474 ms per loop`, whereas `%timeit [f for f in subsample(500,6,12)]` gives `1.71 s per loop`. Note the slightly different conventions for the parameter `w`.